# Java: why a constructor has access modifier?

Tags: java, constructor

For example a class:

```
//class1
class A {
    private A() {  } // why would I make it private?
    public A(int) {  } //why isn't it implicitly public?
}
//class2
class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //A a = new A();
    }
}
```

A constructor instantiates a class so why it has the access modifier? 
Is there a case when we have to declare a constructor *private*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A constructor instantiates a class so why it has the access modifier?

The modifier can be used so you control where the object can be constructed.

> Is there a case when we have to declare a constructor private?

Say you have a factory method like

```
class A {
    private A(int n)  { }

    public static A create(int n) {
        return new A(n);
    }
}
```

or you have a shared constructor which should be called directly.

```
class B {
    public B(int n) {
        this(n, "");
    }
    public B(String str) {
        this(0, str);
    }
    private B(int n, String str) { }
}
```

or you have a Singleton

```
final class Singleton {
    Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    private Singleton() { }
}
```

however I prefer to use an `enum` which has a `private` constructor.

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

or you have a Utility class

```
final class Utils {
    private Utils() { /* don't create one */ }

    public static int method(int n) { }
}
```

however I prefer to use an enum in this case

```
enum Utils {
    /* no instances */;

    public static int method(int n) { }
}
```

Note: if you use a private constructor on a `final` class you can still create instances using nested classes, or reflection.  If you use an `enum` you can't create an instance as easily/accidentally.

Warning: You can create instances of an `enum` using `Unsafe`

---

Note in `enum` the constructor has to be `private`

```
class BuySell {
    BUY(+1), SELL(-1);

    private BuySell(int dir) { }
}
```

You don't have to make it `private` explicitly as this is the default.

Comment: @TheLostMind I call that a utility class, as mentioned at the end. I prefer to use an `enum` which has a private constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The private modifier when applied to a constructor works in much the same way as when applied to a normal method or even an instance variable. Defining a constructor with the private modifier says that only the native class (as in the class in which the private constructor is defined) is allowed to create an instance of the class, and no other caller is permitted to do so. There are two possible reasons why one would want to use a private constructor – the first is that you don’t want any objects of your class to be created at all, and the second is that you only want objects to be created internally – as in only created in your class.

Uses of private construtor:-
1) **Private constructors can be used in the singleton design pattern**
2) **Private constructors can prevent creation of objects**

This might also help [Can a constructor in Java be private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816123/can-a-constructor-in-java-be-private) the use cases of private constructor

Answer (score 0):

Constructor are not responsible for Creating a `object` of a `Class`, these constructor are only responsible for `initialize` the member variables only.

There are various Reason behind this. One of the most popular reason behind this is `design-Pattern`.

```
//class1
class A {
    private A() {  } // why would I make it private?

}
```

> why make private Constructor ?

If you want to make a Class `singleton` then your constructor must be `private`. then only it is possible to make a Class a Singleton.