# Create object from private constructor - eclipse/java bug?

Tags: java, eclipse

Just noticed when I was creating model I'm able to create a **private constructor**... Probably java or eclipse bug just need to confirm. I know it's kinda impossible, but try yourself.

Create an any model ie.

```
//case1
public class Main {

private Main(){}
public Main(Double...doubles ){}
}
```

Normally you couldn't create an object *Main m = new Main();* but when u create an model like that :

```
//case2
public class Main {

private Main(){}
public Main(Double [] doubles ){}
}
```

You are **unable** to create and object *Main m = new Main();*.

Is it how its suppose to be? Will be grateful for any explanation.

**Java :build 1.8.0_131-b11**

**Eclipse : Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a constructor in Java be private?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816123/can-a-constructor-in-java-be-private)

Comment: "Probably java [sic] or eclipse [sic] bug" - umm, yeah, you're never going to have that be the case. Might as well remove that conjecture from your debugging toolkit permanently. That's just wishful magical thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a bug. In case 2, you are actually creating a private constructor which means you cannot instantiate an object of `Main` using the default constructor that takes no `args`. You can only construct an object using the private constructor in the same class where it is defined.

```
public class Main {

     private Main() {
     }

     public Main(Double[] doubles) {
     }

     public void testPrivateConstructor() {
         Main mainObjectInsideTheSameClass = new Main();
     }
 }
```

Your second constructor in case 1 is public and it takes variable number of arguments. So when you create an object using `Main m = new Main()` you are really using the second public constructor and you are passing zero arguments.

One of the specific use cases for case 2 is *singleton pattern* in Java.
Refer: [Can a constructor in Java be private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816123/can-a-constructor-in-java-be-private)

Comment: i can that's all about... try urself

Comment: You cannot create object by `Main m = new Main();`. You would be using the other constructor and passing in a `Double` array..

Comment: did you try? Create an model like i've just write and another class with `public static void main(String[] args) {` and try yourself... maybe its just my eclipse ...

Comment: In your question, you are saying "You are unable to create and object Main m = new Main();" which is exactly how it's supposed to be. So what are you trying to say?

Comment: Why i'm able to create an object in `case 1` and unable to create an object in `case 2`?

Comment: Because your second constructor in case 1 is public and it takes variable number of arguments. So when you create an object using `Main m = new Main()` you are really using the second public constructor and you are passing *zero* arguments.

Answer (score 0):

That's how its supposed to be. You are allowed to create private constructors in Java . Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816123/can-a-constructor-in-java-be-private)

Answer (score 0):

You can use private constructors in any of that class methods (even if that method is static).

Creation of `testA` use `TestA(Double... d)` constructor.
`Double...` it is *varargs* which allows pass zero or multiple arguments.

```
public class Main
{
    private Main()
    {
        System.out.println("Main1");
    }

    public Main(Double[] d)
    {
        System.out.println("Main1 " + (Arrays.toString(d)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestA testA = new TestA(); //match to TestA(Double... d) with zero args
//      TestB testB = new TestB(); //ERROR don't match to TestB(Double[] d)
        Main main = new Main(); //you can use private constructors in class
    }
}

class TestA
{
    private TestA()
    {
        System.out.println("TestA1");
    }

    public TestA(Double... d)
    {
        System.out.println("TestB2 " + (Arrays.toString(d)));
    }
}

class TestB
{
    private TestB()
    {
        System.out.println("TestB1");
    }

    public TestB(Double[] d)
    {
        System.out.println("TestB2 " + (Arrays.toString(d)));
    }
}
```

Out:

```
TestA2 []
Main1
```